# Certificate generation

Tags: ssl, encryption, ssl-certificate

I need to create a certificate for e-mail signing. Due to local regulation I have specific requirements for the certificate and the keys.

I am not a certificate expert at all, so I am totally unsure which kind of certificate I need to buy, whether I need a CSR, how to create the keys.

These are the requirements:

Signature:

1. Hash algorithm: SHA-256 oder SHA-512 (IETF RFC 5754)
2. Signature algorithm: RSASSA-PSS (IETF RFC 4056)

Encryption:

1. Key encryption: RSAES-OAEP (IETF RFC 3447)
2. Content encryption: AES-128 CBC oder AES-192 CBC (IETF RFC 3565).

RSA key length: at least 2048 Bit

Key-Usage: Digital signature, key encryption

Can someone explain which steps I need to perform to get a .cer-file which complys with the above regulation?

Comment: Can you link to the local regulations? Does this need to be a commercial certificate? This question's probably off-topic for SO, unless you plan on generating the certificate yourself (and you probably don't).

Comment: Self-signed is not an option, it needs to be issued be a CA.

Comment: Certificates themselves don't have encryption, so you may be conflating what you need to do with the key and attributes about the certificate.  Certificate Authorities with RSA keys seem to almost always sign with RSASSA-PKCS1; and that's their choice, not yours.

Comment: I am just trying to find out, which of the requirements go to the certificate, which to the keys and which to the program using the keys. I understand that the whole encryption part goes to the program. What about the signature algorithm? @bartonjs

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

1. Acquire the OpenSSL command-line tool.
2. Acquaint yourself with its overall command-line structure.
3. Generate a key-pair with the required characteristics.
4. Generate a CSR with the required characteristics.
5. Submit the CSR (and *not* the key-pair) to a Certificate Signing Authority (CA) stating that it is for signing prtposes, not for SSL.
6. Import the signed certificate and its key chain back into the same files the CSR came from, again via the OpenSSL tool.

Comment: ok, I got OpenSSL. I am able to create a CSR. But I am still not sure which of the needed characterics go to key pay, which go to the certificate and which need to be observed by the program using the keys/certs later. Sorry, that's not really my area of expertise.